# PHP preg_match not getting matches

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to use `preg_match` to pull out some data from a string. The string will have this format:

```
Job Title (1234567) City, State, Country
```

And I'm trying to use this regex to match again it:

```
$pattern = '/(?P<jobTitle>[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+) \((?P<jobCode>[0-9]+)\) (?P<Location>[a-zA-Z0-9,\s]+)/';
preg_match($pattern, $html, $matched_data);
```

Using online regex testers, I'm getting the matches I'm looking for, but when I run this I get this in `$matched_data`:

```
array(0) {
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible that `$html` contains something other than your string? Such as html tags?

Comment: This is a `var_dump()` of $html: `string(69) "Account Executive (12345567) New York, New York, United States"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the problem was some phantom whitespace. This pattern fixed the problem:

```
$pattern = '/(?P<jobTitle>[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+)[\s]+\((?P<jobCode>[0-9]+)\)[\s]+(?P<location>[a-zA-Z0-9,\s]+)/';
```